# Time is not getting properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

```
dtptime  - datetimepicker (Format: Custom Format(HH:mm)
```

Query

```
insert into table1 values (Convert(varchar(8), '" & dtptime & "', 108))
```

The above query is inserting a datevalue instead of time.  I want to insert a time value only.

When i use a current date (getdate()) means it is inserting correctly, but from datetimepicker it is getting only date, not a time.

How to get only a time.

Need query Help

Comment: What's server side language you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert time only, use the code below:

```
--8 represents hh:mm:ss
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (CONVERT(CHAR(8),dt,8))
```

You may see it in action here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/117721/

**Additional Information:**

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) list of conversion codes.

When inserting a time-only value into a `datetime` field, the date will default to `01-01-1900`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to convert the string from datepicker to DateTime object first in the server side app. If you are using C#, you can use the `DateTime` data type. Then use it.

If you are trying to insert, you can use

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
String.Format("insert into table1 values '{0:yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss}'",dt);
```